# How see how many shared memory has the Intel Chipset?

Tags: ram

`free -m` command get this result:

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       7653        1569         296          53        5787        5680
Swap:     16677           0       16677
```

`/proc/meminfo/` get this:

```
MemTotal:        7836716 kB
MemFree:          247608 kB
MemAvailable:    5761416 kB
Buffers:          213056 kB
Cached:          5428304 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          2382164 kB
Inactive:        4671292 kB
Active(anon):    1354928 kB
Inactive(anon):   112176 kB
Active(file):    1027236 kB
Inactive(file):  4559116 kB
nevictable:          48 kB
Mlocked:              48 kB
SwapTotal:      17078268 kB
SwapFree:       17078268 kB
Dirty:              6876 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1412180 kB
Mapped:           523672 kB
Shmem:             55008 kB
Slab:             285340 kB
SReclaimable:     232240 kB
SUnreclaim:        53100 kB
KernelStack:        9536 kB
PageTables:        38648 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    20996624 kB
Committed_AS:    6131060 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      282236 kB
DirectMap2M:     4626432 kB
DirectMap1G:     3145728 kB
```

So the shared memory of the Intel Chipset is 55008 kB (from line Shmem)?
The shared memory is taken from the swap so?
How i can change the size of the shared memory?

I find out that in the bios you can configure (and thus also see) how many ram is shared.

Comment: I think https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307015/what-is-the-meaning-of-shared-memory-in-the-free-command may explain you what you see

Comment: What is your intel processor? ie use: `lscpu | grep Model`